# Pipe grep to less showing the grep command as file name

Tags: linux, grep, filenames, less

`less -M` will show the file name as a prompt, as in:

```
      1 asdf
test.txt lines 1-1/1 (END)
```

I like to pipe grep into less for easier reading.  Can I get less to interpret the grep command as file name for its prompt?

Normally it's just:

`grep asdf test.txt | less` :

```
      1 asdf
lines 1-1/1 (END)
```

I'd like:

`grep asdf test.txt | less` :

```
      1 asdf
grep asdf test.txt lines 1-1/1 (END)
```

I know I could wrap this all in a script and do things with the `$0` arguments but not trying to reinvent the wheel here.

Is this possible with just a couple command line tricks?

Comment: `grep -H`? Isn't it misleading to show the filename anyway, since it's only grep's output...

Comment: I wanted the "file name" as interpreted by `less -M` to be the grep command used; in my example the command was `grep asdf text.txt` which would show as the file name in less, just as a simple reminder of what I looked for in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

`less` has not a clue as to what is on the other side of the pipe that is feeding data to it via standard input, unless someone greatly complicates the code for `less` to find the process group that `less` is running in and other processes in that process group and then who knows how those all fit together (the shell knows this information but may not make it available).

From some reading in `less(1)` one may find the `-P` option to customize the prompt

```
$ echo hi | less -P '?f%f:Standard input'
hi
Standard input
```

so in theory if we can replace the `Standard input` bit with the current shell pipeline...let's see what is `set` when `less` is run...

```
$ function less { set > whatisset; command less "$@"; }
$ echo foo | less
foo
$ egrep 'echo|foo' whatisset
$
```

so nothing obvious to use for `mksh`, as `echo` or `foo` (equivalent to your `grep`) do not appear anywhere in the shell environment (same story for `zsh` and oh wow does `bash` on Linux ever spam the environment with settings but again same story). Actually, with `zsh` we can use a `preexec` function to make the command line available:

```
$ zsh
% function preexec { shift; SHORT=$1; }
% function less { set > whatisset; command less "$@"; }
% echo foo | less
foo
% grep SHORT whatisset
SHORT='echo foo | less'
%
```

so one could do something like

```
% less() { =less -P '?f%f:'${SHORT%% | less} "$@"; }
% echo hi|less
hi
echo hi
```

Comment: Cool thanks.  So it seems the long and short of it is it can be done in zsh but not so easily in bash.  As I thought, nothing simply.  Thanks for detailed answer though, always great to learn new things.

Answer (score 0):

I went against myself and wrote a little script that accomplishes this.  It's not pretty but it works, and not bad as it's only a few lines.  Always up for improvements.

```
#!/bin/bash

# store all args as string
allargs="$*"

# create temp file named as grep command
TMPFILE=$(mktemp -q "$allargs")

# run grep command
$* --color=always > "$TMPFILE" # --color=always with less -r will highlight results in less

# show results file in less
less -Mr "$TMPFILE"

# delete the temp file
rm -f -- "$TMPFILE"
```

Run as `./scriptname grep <opts> <regex> <file(s)>`.

Downside: if `file` is `*` (search all in current dir) then they are expanded and made as part of the file name which defeats the purpose as it pushes the command off the screen (very long file name).  Unless there's a way to scroll the file name horizontally in `less`?